# Nesting PageView: Change the outer PageView when the inner PageView reaches the end

Tags: flutter

Consider a [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) usage where we have one [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) inside another one:

```dart
PageView(
  children: [
    Container(color: Colors.red),
    Column(
      children: [
        Text('Title'),
        PageView(
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.green),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
);
```

Such architecture will allow us to transition between the outer [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) to the inner [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html). But once we reached the inner [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) we can't get out anymore.

Here's a gif showcasing it:

[image]

In such architecture, we can't "merge" both [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)s into one, because the inner [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) doesn't fill the screen

How could we achieve a similar result while allowing to transition from both [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) without getting stuck?

Comment: Looks like PageController  extends ScrollController . So you may try writing a CustomPageController that scroll the inner and outer PageViews in sync. You may get some idea from here. https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/blob/master/lib/src/linked_scroll_controller/linked_scroll_controller.dart

Comment: apparently , what you need is SliverPageView widget which is not available in the framework for some reason

Comment: @SaedNabil That's not a SliverPageView because of the "title".

Comment: @RémiRousselet I think title can be sticky header but translated to it is place , it is just a hypothitical view as there is no such a component of SliverPageView

Answer (score 4):

I have a workaround using `NotificationListener` by controlling the page view with `PageController`. The user actually control the lower PageView and pass the offset to the higher PageView.

```
final _pageController1 = PageController(); // Controlled
final _pageController2 = PageController(); // Controller

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var leftOverScroll = 0.0; // total over-scroll offset on left side
  var rightOverScroll = 0.0;

  return PageView(
    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    controller: _pageController1,
    children: [
      Container(color: Colors.red),
      Column(
        children: [
          const Text('Title'),
          Expanded(
            child: NotificationListener(
              onNotification: (notification) {
                // over scroll to the left side
                if (notification is OverscrollNotification &&
                    notification.overscroll < 0) {
                  leftOverScroll += notification.overscroll;
                  _pageController1.position.correctPixels(
                      _pageController1.position.pixels +
                          notification.overscroll);
                  _pageController1.position.notifyListeners();
                }

                // scroll back after left over scrolling
                if (leftOverScroll < 0) {
                  if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                    final newOverScroll = math.min(
                        notification.metrics.pixels + leftOverScroll, 0.0);
                    final diff = newOverScroll - leftOverScroll;
                    _pageController1.position.correctPixels(
                        _pageController1.position.pixels + diff);
                    _pageController1.position.notifyListeners();
                    leftOverScroll = newOverScroll;
                    _pageController2.position.correctPixels(0);
                    _pageController2.position.notifyListeners();
                  }
                }

                // release left
                if (notification is UserScrollNotification &&
                    notification.direction == ScrollDirection.idle &&
                    leftOverScroll != 0) {
                  _pageController1.previousPage(
                      curve: Curves.ease,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
                  leftOverScroll = 0;
                }

                // over scroll to the right side
                if (notification is OverscrollNotification &&
                    notification.overscroll > 0) {
                  rightOverScroll += notification.overscroll;
                  _pageController1.position.correctPixels(
                      _pageController1.position.pixels +
                          notification.overscroll);
                  _pageController1.position.notifyListeners();
                }

                // scroll back after right over scrolling
                if (rightOverScroll > 0) {
                  if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                    final maxScrollExtent =
                        notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent;
                    final newOverScroll = math.max(
                        notification.metrics.pixels +
                            rightOverScroll -
                            maxScrollExtent,
                        0.0);
                    final diff = newOverScroll - rightOverScroll;
                    _pageController1.position.correctPixels(
                        _pageController1.position.pixels + diff);
                    _pageController1.position.notifyListeners();
                    rightOverScroll = newOverScroll;
                    _pageController2.position.correctPixels(maxScrollExtent);
                    _pageController2.position.notifyListeners();
                  }
                }

                // release right
                if (notification is UserScrollNotification &&
                    notification.direction == ScrollDirection.idle &&
                    rightOverScroll != 0) {
                  _pageController1.nextPage(
                      curve: Curves.ease,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
                  rightOverScroll = 0;
                }

                return false;
              },
              child: PageView(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _pageController2,
                children: [
                  Container(color: Colors.green),
                  Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(color: Colors.blue),
    ],
  );
}
```

For the part how to avoid the notifications come from the other child widget, I can only think of wrapping it with another `NotificationListener`

```
NotificationListener(
  onNotification: (_)=> true,
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (ctx,index) => Container(width: 50,color: Colors.primaries[index%Colors.primaries.length],),
  ),
),
```

### Result:

[image]

At the end:

- I only handle the left side over scroll of the PageView
- To keep it simple, I don't implement the PageScrollPhysic when the drag come to end (calculated by velocity and page position).

Comment: It work great, can you update to handle the right side over scroll of the PageView?

Comment: I slightly updated the example code to describe how the right part is handled. Please notice this workaround may need more tunning on edge case.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I confirm that it's worked great. I will update if it has any issues

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be using Notification listener and animateToPage:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: PageView(
        controller: _parentController,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('0'),
            ),
          ),
          NotificationListener<OverscrollNotification>(
            onNotification: (notification) {
              if (notification.overscroll < 0)
                _parentController.animateToPage(0,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart);
              if (notification.overscroll > 0)
                _parentController.animateToPage(2,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart);
              return false;
            },
            child: PageView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Center(child: Text('2: 0')),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(child: Text('2: 1')),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('2'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This works only on IOS (android us ea glow instead of overscroll). And it is controller programmatically instead of with the touch, which is undesired

Comment: @RémiRousselet But I implemented an tested it successfully on android!

Comment: You can't use NotificationListener for this anyway. If there's a ListView inside the PageView that could have undesired effects. And again, the transition should be controller using touch, not through `animateToPage`